# How do I create the formula for calculate the damage of a skill

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need a formula for determine the amount of damage that a skill or ability can do.

I have some data that I don't have create myself, but I just taken from a game.

A character can grow up from lv 1 to 100, and he has a set of skills.

Every skill can go up from lv 1 to (current level of the character)

The skill damage is linear but influenced of character's attack, so more attack the character has and more damage can do the skill.

A character that we call John has the follow parameters

Max stats that John can reach:

- Level 100
- Attack 7337
- Skill damage (lv 100) 16574

Minimum stats:

- Level 1
- Attack 71
- Skill damage (lv 1) 479

The current stats of John:

- Level 13
- Attack 202
- Skill damage (lv 13) 805

When the skill was a previous level:

- Level 13
- Attack 202
- Skill damage (lv 12) 788

In theory the skill damage should get 7 points for level, of course with the current amount attack of John, but is linear.

What I'm trying to do is get the basic damage of a skill plus the correct multiplier

Edit:

Seems that adding an item that give a bonus (+62 atk) the multiplier is change from 7 to 18 and the skill damage increased of +64 (788,852)

- Level 13
- Attack 264(202+62 from equip)
- Skill damage (lv 12) 852
- Level 13
- Attack 264(202+62 from equip)
- Skill damage (lv 13) 870

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a satisfying answer, but I think it's at least more than a comment.

It's not possible to answer this exactly without all the knowledge of the game (because there might be some non-linearities going on), but solving a linear system can give us an approximate answer. The linear system assumes that the answer is of the form

$$
\text{skill damage} = A \times \text{Level} + B\times \text{Attack} + C\times \text{Skill level} + D
$$
Plugging in the values that you have given, we get the equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcrcrcl}
100 A  &+& 7337 B  &+& 100 C  &+& D  &= 16574 \\
A  &+& 71 B  &+& C  &+& D  &= 479 \\
13 A  &+& 202 B  &+& 13 C  &+& D  &= 805 \\
13 A  &+& 202 B  &+& 12 C  &+& D  &= 788 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Solving this gives us an approximate answer
$$
\text{skill damage} = -13.5 \times \text{Level} + 2\times \text{Attack} + 17\times \text{Skill level} + 321
$$
But this seems weird, because the Level multiplier is negative. This serves as evidence that the equation is more complicated than what we assumed.